# Roots of a polynomial with real cofficients

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, polynomials

Good evening;

Let $\alpha, \beta \in\mathbb{R}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Please can you help me to  prove that every polynomial of the form

$$ f(x)=x^{n+3}+\alpha x+\beta $$

admits at most 3 reals roots. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the second derivative has at most one real root.

Comment: thank you very much @Robert Israel

Comment: thank you very much   @Martin Argerami

Comment: [continued] If $\lambda_i$, $1\leq i \leq n+3$, be eigenvalues of $C_f$ matrix, we know that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+3}\lambda_i=trac(C_f)=0 \qquad \& \qquad  \prod_{i=1}^{n+3} \lambda_{i}=det(C_f)=\pm\beta
$$

How above relations result that the function $f$ have at most 3 reals roots. Thanks

Comment: Those two don't: they would be the same if there was a term in $x^2$, and then you might have more real roots (e.g. $x^{n+3} - x^2$ has three real roots if $n$ is odd).

Comment: Excuse me, I accidently removed my first comment.  Thanks for your hint.

Comment: Dear Mr Israel, I want to ask you if it is possible answer this question. the companion matrix of the function $f$, is as follows
$$
C_f=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
0 &1 &0 &\cdots &\cdots &0 \\
0 &0 &1 &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots \\
\vdots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots \\
\vdots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &0 \\
0 &\cdots &\cdots &0 &0 &1 \\
\beta &\alpha &0&0 &0 &0 \\
\end{array}
\right)_{(n+3) \times (n+3)}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Between any two real roots, the derivative has to be zero. Here $$f'(x)=(3+n)x^{n+2}+\alpha.$$ This has at most two real roots if $n$ is even, or one if $n$ is odd.